# How do I make an UDP listener that doesn't crash the program?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, networking

Hi i am making a fire alarm program. Currently I am implementing the networking code.
I have used code from the [msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) every time I run the program it will just sit and load for ever. 
heres the current code i am using.

```
   Public Shared Sub StartListener()
    Dim done As Boolean = False
    Dim listener As New UdpClient(listenPort)
    Dim groupEP As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort)
    Try
        While Not done
            Dim bytes As Byte() = listener.Receive(groupEP)
            If Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) = "FIRE" Then
                My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.firealarm, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
            End If
        End While
    Finally
        listener.Close()
    End Try
End Sub 'StartListener
```

This program is meant to be server-less

Comment: You never set `done` to `True`, so the while loop will keep going; so if you are running this in the UI  thread, it will seem like your application "crashed" (the UI is not responding).

Comment: @Styxxy i need it to constantly check

Comment: So check it in another thread. You could use a `BackgroundWorker` for it.

Comment: @Styxxy the While Not done is a vb.net version of python while True: is used insted of a timer

Comment: `While True` can also be done in VB.NET.

Comment: @Styxxy im using a background prossess now. i need to open a form but doing it the normal way opens it as part of the background worker how do i make it open not part of it

Comment: Two seconds searching yields me this result (second hit): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6811993/578843

Comment: `While Not done` will produce a `StackOverflow`.

Comment: The `done` variable are never evaluated, thus the program crashes. The condition are _always_ met. It's like saying: `Do While True = True`.